# How to share ethernet connection on Ubuntu (Jaunty)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I've googled it and I've found mostly tutorials on sharing when having 2 ethernet ports. I am in a hotel with only wired connection (eth0). I would like to use my wifi card to share my connection with other computers and be able to switch the wifi back to its normal status so I can use it outside the hotel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/ShareEthernetConnectionThroughWireless) is a page documenting setting up an ad-hoc access point.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up IP routing. See [my answer to a similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/35307/how-to-forward-wlan0-to-eth0/35374#35374).