# Using Connection of one PC on another

Tags: c, linux

I have two linux PC and connected through LAN cable.First PC having internet connection but second does not.I want second PC to use the connection of first PC through a C program.

I am new to network programming.Any help will be appreciated.Please suggest where to start.

THNX.

Comment: There's no need to write a program to do this. What you need to do is bridge the connection between the two computers. There are several posts on Super User about this already: [How to share internet connection in Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/q/169344/), [Share internet in Linux](http://superuser.com/q/162172), [Bridging network connections in Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/323174).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want your C program to be able to access internet through another PC? Or you want to develop a utility using which any C program can do such thing? If former you must look into existing facilities on linux for sharing connections. See this [link](http://jorgenmodin.net/index_html/archive/2008/11/13/how-to-do-internet-connection-sharing-on-linux/view) for example.

The point is, unless you want to write network utilities, your C program -- or any other program for that matter -- should use whatever internet connection is available on the host computer. For general programs the detail of how the host computer connects to internet is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into some sort of source programs such as [3proxy](http://www.3proxy.ru/current/3proxy-0.7-devel.tgz)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forward connection over a secure connection, use tcpip forwarding of SSH.

http://www.libssh.org/